# Is there a way to display this only once?

Tags: recursion, iteration, sml, converters, radix

I wrote this sml function that allows me to display the first 5 columns of the Ascii table.

```
fun radix (n, base) =
    let
        val b = size base
        val digit = fn n => str (String.sub (base, n))
        val radix' =
            fn (true, n) => digit n
            | (false, n) => radix (n div b, base) ^ digit (n mod b)
    in
        radix' (n < b, n)
    end;

val n = 255;
val charList = List.tabulate(n+1, 
  fn x => print(
      "DEC"^"\t"^"OCT"^"\t"^"HEX"^"\t"^"BIN"^"\t"^"Symbol"^"\n"^
      Int.toString(x)^"\t"^
      radix (x, "01234567")^"\t"^
      radix (x, "0123456789abcdef")^"\t"^
      radix (x, "01")^"\t"^
      Char.toCString(chr(x))^"\t"
  )
);
```

But I want the header : `"DEC"^"\t"^"OCT"^"\t"^"HEX"^"\t"^"BIN"^"\t"^"Symbol"` to be displayed only once at the beginning, but I can't do it. Does anyone know a way to do it?

On the other hand I would like to do without the resursive call of the "radix" function. Is that possible? And is it a wise way to write this function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want the header : `"DEC"...` to be displayed only once at the beginning

Currently the header displays multiple times because it is being `print`ed inside of `List.tabulate`'s function, once for each number in the table. So you can move printing the header outside of this function and into a parent function.

For clarity I might also move the printing of an individual character into a separate function. (I think you have indented the code in your `charList` very nicely, but if a function does more than one thing, it is doing too many things.)

E.g.

```
fun printChar (i : int) =
    print (Int.toString i ^ ...)

fun printTable () =
    ( print "DEC\tOCT\tHEX\tBIN\tSymbol\n"
    ; List.tabulate (256, printChar)
    ; ()  (* why this? *)
    )
```

It is very cool that you found `Char.toCString` which is safe compared to simply printing any character. It seems to give some pretty good names for e.g. `\t` and `\n`, but hardly for every function. So if you really want to spice up your table, you could add a helper function,

```
fun prettyName character =
    if Char.isPrint character
    then ...
    else case ord character of
         0 => "NUL (null)"
       | 1 => "SOH (start of heading)"
       | 2 => "STX (start of text)"
       | ...
```

and use that instead of `Char.toCString`.

Whether to print a character itself or some description of it might be up to [`Char.isPrint`](https://smlfamily.github.io/Basis/char.html#SIG:CHAR.isPrint:VAL).

> I would like to do without the resursive call of the "radix" function.
>
> Is that possible?
>
> And is it a wise way to write this function?

You would need something equivalent to your `radix` function either way.

Sure, it seems okay. You could shorten it a bit, but the general approach is good.

You have avoided list recursion by doing `String.sub` constant lookups. That's great.